# Javascript selecting specific content from a website from an RSS feed

Tags: javascript, html

We are trying to use the [FeedEk](https://github.com/enginkizil/FeedEk) RSS Feed Plugin to display an RSS feed. We have this working just fine. This is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/argilmour/sgd18Lwb/) showing this.

What we are now trying to do is figure out a way that when a user clicks a news item link they are taken to a new page that displays only part of the original page - I want to display just the article based on this snippet:

```
<div class="article">

        <div class="headline">

            <h1 class="title">

                    <a href="/fe-news/fe-needs-a-different-kind-of-e-learning-model">FE needs a different kind of e-Learning model</a>

            </h1>
```

- the rest of the article

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can use xpath/css selectors to select exactly the content you need.

Comment: @mukesh hi mukesh - do you possibly have an example?

Comment: So you want to display the linked article inline in your page? No, that is not practically possible.

Comment: I've invested some time to make some general improvements over your initial approach, primarily by introducing a client-side HTML templating engine (handlebars). It doesn't exactly answer your question, but I don't want to throw it away either. So here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sgd18Lwb/2/